# What is the technical programming term for concatenating two variables in order to fit a restraint only to seperate them later down the line?

Tags: terminology

I discovered it when working with PHP and an API. I haven't seen it used for years as languages have become more programmer-friendly.

Context:
I have a program that takes in X number pieces of data of arbitrary size. This data is passed through to an API that returns some information based on such given data sent.

Now, the API only has fields for x-1 pieces of data so to get around this I would concatenate two pieces of X, say x1 & x2, with a known character in between. I would generally use ":" in the case I'm describing so the API would be sent X-1 pieces of data, one of which being x1:x2. This x1:x2 piece would be part of what was returned so on the receiving script of my server I would write a simple function (possibly a method) to split this data on the ":" character, assigning one side to a variable and the other to another.

How would a professional computer scientist describe this technique?

Comment: In the Perl community, that is called a "Schwartzian transform" after Randall L Schwartz, who was instrumental in Perl's development.  In Perl, it is commonly used for sorting on an unusual key.  You transform the data into a form that sorts naturally, do the sort, then unwind back to the original format.

Comment: Database persons would call this a composite key.

Comment: Honestly, I'd just call it a delimited value - not fancy, but just about everyone should understand exactly what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually referred to as marshalling.